# The best European Sound Design Courses at Postgraduate level?

Tags: design, studies, europe, course

Hello all you social sound designers out there...

I am going to study Film & Moving Image Production this September at University.

I am already looking forward to what I want to do with the qualification after I have completed the course, as I am a mature student.

Can anyone advise on any Film Sound Design MA/MSc Courses that they recommend throughout Europe?

I have already seen the course available at NFTS here in the UK and was wondering if that is the best possible course I could do... they have Walter Murch and Chris Watson visit and do guest lectures/tuition.

I just want to know whats out there really, there are so many things that pop up in a google search that I don't know where to begin looking!

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help or suggest where to look.

I know its not a good idea to get ahead of myself, but I do want to know where I am going as it drives me forward through things like Uni with motivation do get the work done.

- Zimon

Comment: Also, I would prefer a course that is very practical and hands on but includes a necessary amount of research based study...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Zimon,

Great that you're starting a film course at the university. Your question needs a little more explanation though. Do you already have practical field experience? What do you want to do during your Post graduate study? 
I've 'used' my Post graduate course to develop my sound design as well as my conceptual skills on project level. Meaning I initiated projects during my course that allowed me to be two things at once, a sound designer and a director. They were mostly radioplays/theatreplays and installations. This was all based on my MA course at the Utrecht School of Arts and for me a natural evolution. A school I can totally recommend btw.

Where do you come from and where do want to go?

Arnoud
The Netherlands

Comment: Hello Arnoud, thanks for your reply. I come from the UK, Norfolk more specifically. I do not have any practical field experience, I wish to develop my skills in all aspects of sound for film, on a technical level and from an artistic/creative approach. I really want to go to the continent just to experience life abroad as a student and to develop my language abilities. I will have to look at the Utrecht school of Arts. I have just realised that the University I am going to also offers an MA course in Moving image and sound. The university is called NUCA Norwich University College of the Arts..

Comment: Well, all i can say is this: Spent your time wisely, most Postgraduate courses don't accept students without any field experience. So invest in a basic but decent sound design kit (DAW, mic(s), recorder) and start working on stuff. In my opinion you can only study sound design by doing it, experiencing the process, reflect on that and move forward. Read as much as you can and talk about it with classmates and especially the teachers/professionals. Oh and enjoy other art forms as well, they'll inspire you! Good luck and enjoy.

Comment: excellent response, thank you I really appreciate the advice

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have taken the MA in post production sound on NFTS.
I don't really know how to measure quality of a grad or MA course. But since these courses generally are connected to the rest of the school, sound students cater for the projects and productions of other lines, which gives great amount of work experience, but makes the planning of the course is very complex. Be prepared for a stressful work environment where there is not much time to reflect. You do learn how to be creative in the NFTS sound department, but it's not easy to imply it in the projects, was my experience.
 Also flagship brands like Walther are available in book form and on youtube. You spend time with them and you might be going deeper. I guess a school like that tries to give what the average university can't. The ability to understand and apply experience. But that's in a way also a personal thing. It's hard to develop a balanced lifestyle and general approach, while going all in on the film work. The school can't offer this. But being in balance as a person in this business, is really needed. If you are talented or not. If you are good or not. 
If you are nice and relaxed with small demands you last longer.